# Error while connecting Spring-Hibernate Application to MySQL Database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

**In my Spring Web Application (Spring version - 4.2), I was trying to connect Hibernate 5.1 to MySQL Database. But I'm getting following error on Tomcat startup**

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to
>   obtain JDBC Connection

Please help me to resolve this issue!
Here is my `DataSource` Bean and `sessionFactory` Bean

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">  
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>  
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"></property>  
    <property name="username" value="root"></property>  
    <property name="password" value="root"></property>  
    <property name="initialSize" value="1"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="10"/>
</bean>  
 <bean id="sessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">  
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property> 
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.testproject.hibernate.entity"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">  
        <props>  
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>  
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>  
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>          
            <prop key="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>          
        </props>  
    </property>  
</bean>
```

Comment: there must be something wrong with the jdbc connection parameters. does the provided jdbc url work outside of your application?

Comment: Please, add the full stack trace.

Comment: Im using same Jdbc connection parameters from terminal and it's working fine!!